# how to count the open files without lsof

Tags: linux, redhat, lsof, proc, file-descriptors

we have in our cluster more then 800 rhel machines - version 7.2

since `lsof | wc -l`

take too much time ( sometimes 3-4 min ) , in order to get the current open files

we want to know if there are other approach that can give the total current open files in short time

*note - in our case , we have 835 linux machines , so it will be very bad to use `lsof | wc -`l on all machines*  , according to our calculation it will take 40~hours

Comment: Most lines counted by `lsof | wc -l` are not open files. In addition you may have to tell apart open files from file descriptors as several processes can have opened the same file.

Comment: The exactly same question, one hour apart, by different users...? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/584535/how-to-count-the-open-files-without-lsof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `root`:

```
find /proc/[1-9]*/fd/ -mindepth 1 -printf . 2>/dev/null | wc -c
```

Comment: Or easiert: `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr`